# cv2.inRange() make it work for all inputs

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCv (4.x) on Anime Sketch dataset from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ktaebum/anime-sketch-colorization-pair) to get the image's silhouette. What I found to be the hardest part was to detect that empty areas inside that silhouette, areas  between arm-body, legs and hair. The tutorials I followed always use "full filled" objects, like a ball, head or cars and I ended up tunning that code to make it work, but it is too specific so that tunning just work ok on one image.

Playing around in [online-image-editor.com](https://www.online-image-editor.com/?language=english) I've noticed that I can use the tool called Trans-parency to change one color, just like cv2.inRange() does.

Original image [image]
The code:

```
image = cv2.imread("2.png",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
crop_img = image[:, 0:512]
fuzz_factor = 0.97
maxColor = (crop_img[1,1] * 1).astype(int)
minColor = (maxColor * fuzz_factor).astype(int)
mask = cv2.inRange(crop_img, minColor, maxColor)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

and outputs this (not that bad..)

[image]

BUT then trying with another image it doesn't work anymore, output:
[image]

So, question(s):

- There is some "magic rule" where I can extract a specific fuzz_factor for each image?
- How could I use the image's right half to get that silhouette/contour?

Thanks guys

Comment: you could try Otsu thresholding or stuff like color histograms. In then end there will always be cases that wont work unless your algorithm has a perfect image understanding.

Comment: I've tried with **cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)** and **cv2.grabCut()** also, but the outputs are less consistent, I'll try color histograms

Comment: any assumption like "background is always the most dominant color"? "background is always bright"? You might need to find the biggest contours to fill segmentation gaps/holes (there can always be bright regions inside of an object).

Answer (score 0):

I post to close this question.

Thanks to [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka) I made some progress, there are two variables that have high impact on output's quality:

- fuzz_factor: which sets the color range for cv2.inRange()
- max_contours: number of contours to draw (sorted by size)

High numbers are better until there are white zones that are not background, so next thing could be discard that ones.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# constants
fuzz_factor = 1
max_contours = -10
image_path = "9.png"

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image =  image[:, 0:512]

# background color boundaries
color = image[3,3]
upper = (color).astype(int)
lower = (color * (100 - fuzz_factor/2.0)/100).astype(int)

# create mask with specific colors
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

# get all contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, mode = cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method = cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if(len(contours) > 1):
    # get the [max_contours] biggest areas
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[max_contours:]
    # mask where contours are filled
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    # draw contours and fill
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, color=[255,255,255], thickness= -1)

    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, 255, 2)
    cv2.imshow("Result", np.hstack([image, mask]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```